# groupsize vs execution time?

Tags: opencl

I make a simple program abput a vector adder and want to test the execution time vs the groupsize.
when I change the groupsize from 1024 to 5012 to 256 and to 128. The execution time is very similar. Why? in my view, when I `use smaller groupsizes, we should have more groups and they can work in the cores in parallel which could lead less execution time(for example, if workgroupsize change from 512 to 256, the execution time should reduce half?) but in my experinment in gpu, the execution time is siilar?  is my view wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Because number of workitems per group is not a visible bottleneck for vector addition. The global memory performance ise bottleneck. If data comes from host then pci-e performance is also bottleneck.